# Plot list of plots in GGiraph

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggiraph

I am trying to plot a list of plots using GGiraph in Rstudio.
The solution to plot multiple plots is either through Cowplot (`ggobj = plot_grid(plot1, plot2)`) or Patchwork (`code = print(plot / plot)`). This works if you individually print single plots. However, it looks like it does not accept a list of plots. I want the plots to be arranged in one column with multiple rows.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Can you create a minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the `plotlist` argument in `plot_grid`.

```r
#Using the example from giraffe
library(ggiraph)
library(ggplot2)

dataset <- mtcars
dataset$carname = row.names(mtcars)

gg_point = ggplot( data = dataset,
    mapping = aes(x = wt, y = qsec, color = disp,
    tooltip = carname, data_id = carname) ) +
  geom_point_interactive() + theme_minimal()

#using the plotlist argument
library(cowplot)
girafe(ggobj = plot_grid(plotlist=list(gg_point, gg_point), ncol=1))
```

Comment: Glad it does! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with [functional assembly in `patchwork`](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/guides/assembly.html#functional-assembly), using the `wrap_plots()` function and the `ncol` or `nrow` arguments. `wrap_plots()` can take either a series of graphs or a list.

```
library(ggiraph)
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

# Demo figure
g <- ggplot(data = mpg, aes(x = cyl, y = hwy, color = class,
                            tooltip = model, data_id = model)) +
  geom_point_interactive()

# Use wrap_plots from patchwork
g <- wrap_plots(list(g, g), ncol = 1)
girafe(ggobj = g)
```